# xquery multiple maximum values

Tags: xml, xquery

How do i return all the maximum values in xquery? I used max() but it only gives me one! Thanks.

```
<id>a</id>
<average>5</average>
<id>b</id>
<average>5</average>
<id>c</id>
<average>5</average>
<id>d</id>
<average>4</average>
<id>e</id>
<average>1</average>
```

and i want my results to be:

```
<id>a</id>
<id>b</id>
<id>c</id>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The XML input you specified doesn’t seem to be a single, well-formed document. Could you show how your original XML document looks like? For example, is there any root node for all listed elements?

Comment: So basically this is how the xml looks. 
   <sta>
      <id>a</id>
      <name>Name</name>
      <developer>Adams</developer>
      <average>5</average>
   </sta>
And I need to return the id and the average for the ones that have the highest rating. And multiple elements can have the highest rating.

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback; as I’ve seen, Dimitre has already given a fine answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/id[following-sibling::*[1]/number() eq max(/*/average)]
```

The above is both a correct XQuery and a correct XPath 2.0 solution.

**Verification with Saxon EE 9.3.04 XQuery**:

When the above XQUery is applied on the following XML document (the provided fragment, wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <id>a</id>
    <average>5</average>
    <id>b</id>
    <average>5</average>
    <id>c</id>
    <average>5</average>
    <id>d</id>
    <average>4</average>
    <id>e</id>
    <average>1</average>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><id>a</id><id>b</id><id>c</id>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied (using Saxon 9.1.05) on the same XML document** (above):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "/*/id[following-sibling::*[1]/number() eq max(/*/average)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**again the same correct result is produced:**

```
<id>a</id>
<id>b</id>
<id>c</id>
```